# End to end tests of a flutter web app using Katalon?

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, katalon

Our tester is used to do his integration (end to end) tests using Katalon and don't know Dart language. At first glance, the tool does not recognize the elements of a flutter web app.

We have tried

```
--web-renderer html
```

command on build. But it doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there a way to achieve end to end tests on a flutter web app using Katalon?